# Spray routing - unmarshalling using InputStream

Tags: inputstream, unmarshalling, spray

I am trying out [spray.io](http://spray.io/) to write a basic REST endpoint that accepts a file from a client via multipart/form-data.

My route looks something like this:

```
val route = {
  post {
    path("upload") {
      respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) {
        entity(as[MultipartFormData]) {
          formData => {
            formField("file") {
              file => {
                val fileBodyPart: BodyPart = formData.get("file").get
                val fileData: InputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileBodyPart.entity.data.toByteArray)
                // do something with the InputStream and respond
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My concern is that the `data.toByteArray` call will read the whole file into memory. I'd like to read this directly as an InputStream instead so I can play with arbitrarily large files.

If I were using [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/), I'd just use something like:

```
@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream
```

as a parameter in the method that defines my REST resource. Is there an equivalent to this in Spray?

Thanks.

Comment: The data already is in memory. Streaming `MulpartFormData` support is currently not supported in spray. See this example workaround for how to handle file uploads with the current version: https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/examples/spray-can/simple-http-server/src/main/scala/spray/examples/FileUploadHandler.scala

Comment: Thanks @jrudolph. I will look into the example.